# I am trying to randomly populate my vector with two strings in R but I am getting NAs

Tags: r

I am trying to randomly populate my vector with Yes's and No's but I am getting No's and NA's. Why is this?

```
> mydata$Answer[sample(1:2,nrow(mydata),TRUE,prob = c(.01,.99))]<-rep(Answer)
> mydata$Answer
  [1] NA   "No" NA   "No" NA   "No" NA   "No" NA   "No" NA   "No" NA   "No" NA   "No" NA   "No" NA   "No"
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  What is `mydata$Answer`

Comment: I think that you want `mydata$Answer = c("Yes", "No")[sample(1:2,nrow(mydata),TRUE,prob = c(.01,.99))]`